# "SyntaxError: invalid quantifier" for no reason

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, firebug

This occurs in Mozilla Firefox 18.0.2 with Firebug 1.11.1.

For no reason at all and not related to regex whatsoever, I've been getting 'invalid quantifier' errors all over the place and when I try to debug it, its pointed to jQuery and usually related to calling object property via variable e.g :-

```
var propValue = elem[prop];
```

My site is a valid HTML5 and this error only occurs in Firefox. Chrome, Opera, Safari and surprisingly IE works fine without error whatsoever.

I've been googling this for a while and still couldn't find a solution. I'm not even sure if its a bug in Firefox or Firebug. Definitely not the scripts because it works fine in all other browsers. I've tried moving the js to the head but its worst because apparently the jQuery `prop` seems to begin to run before the dom is fully loaded, causing even more errors.

It also seems that the errors do not break when I clear my cache. But when I reload the page again, then the errors will break.

Anyone has an idea what's causing this?

Screen 1:

[image]

Screen 2:

[image]

Comment: What is `elem` and `prop`?

Comment: Try using an uncompressed version of jQuery in order to get a better understanding of what's going on. Here's 1.9.1 uncompressed: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js

Comment: Can you link to a page using an unminified version of your script and jQuery that shows the problem?